# Find minimum and maximum date for what a person can be born for a certain age

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm using Laravel which has Carbon dating built in. I'm wondering what the best way to figure out the minimum and maximum dates a person can be born to be a certain age. For instance a 33 year old can be born between x and y. So far I'm guessing the minimum is something like

```
$age = 33;   
$minimum =  Carbon::today()->subYears($age)->toDateString();
```

But how do I find the maximum? I know I need to - 1 on the sub years plus a day but can't figure out how?

Comment: `subYears($age-1)` there is a start for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are 33 as of today (2018-02-22), it means either

- It's your birthday today, you just turn 33: Your birthday is **1985-02-22**
- Today is your last day as 33, tomorrow is your 34<sup>th</sup> birthday. Your birthday should be **1984-02-23**

So we know that the date range should be from **1984-02-23** to **1985-02-22**, which translates to:

```
// Today = 2018-02-22

// Maximum = Today - 33 years ago
//         = 2018-02-22 - 33 years
//         = 1985-02-22
$max = Carbon::today()->subYears($age)->toDateString();

// Minimum = Tomorrow - 34 years ago
//         = 2018-02-23 - 34 years
//         = 1984-02-23
$min = Carbon::tomorrow()->subYears($age + 1)->toDateString();
```

Comment: Lol, just posted the same thing without seeing your answer first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your syntax is correct for your `$minimum` calculation, you can use the equivalent methods from Carbon:

```
$maximum = Carbon::today()->subYears($age - 1)->addDay()->toDateString();
```

Check out the carbon docs [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are question this:

What is the minimun and maximum date so a person can have `X` years considering his/her age until today.

So lets imagine my son was born a year ago. He will be `1` year old until `02/20/2019`, then he will turn `2`. so he will be `1` year from `02/21/2018` (like today) until `02/20/2019` (like yesterday).

Given this example you can guess this to know those limits, if I'm not wrong:

```
$age = 33;   
$minimum =  Carbon::today()->subYears($age)->toDateString();
$maximum = Carbon::yesterday()->subYears($age-1)->toDateString();
```

Give it a try.

---

The are a lot more methods in the Carbon library. Check the [documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out I think, needed to add year not remove, and do it based on tomorrow.

```
$age = 30;
$minimum =  Carbon::today()->subYears($age)->toDateString();
$maximum = Carbon::tomorrow()->subYears($age + 1)->toDateString();
```